# Mongodb error : The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument mongodb 3.6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongodb(ver 3.6) Aggregation not working. Previously I used mongodb 3.4 and mongoose 4.7.0.

```
Books.aggregate([{
            $match: filter
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'user_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user'
            }
        }], function(err, list) {
```

The above code was working fine with mongodb 3.4. But after update mongodb to 3.6, the aggregation is not working. It throws the following error

```
The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
```

Due to many dependencies I can't update mongoose also. So is there any way to resolve this issue with mongoose 4.7.0?

Answer (score 0):

[AGGREGATIONCURSOR Cannot directly be instantiated](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/)

Example

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const test = require('assert');
// Connection url
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
// Database Name
const dbName = 'test';
// Connect using MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  // Create a collection we want to drop later
  const col = client.db(dbName).collection('createIndexExample1');
  // Insert a bunch of documents
  col.insert([{a:1, b:1}
    , {a:2, b:2}, {a:3, b:3}
    , {a:4, b:4}], {w:1}, function(err, result) {
    test.equal(null, err);
    // Show that duplicate records got dropped
    col.aggregation({}, {cursor: {}}).toArray(function(err, items) {
      test.equal(null, err);
      test.equal(4, items.length);
      client.close();
    });
  });
});
```